# How can I address the path/file I just specified again?

Tags: bash, command-line, arguments

Say I'll start writing

```
sudo cp /etc/var/more/evenMORE/fileABC
```

and as the target of the copying, I'd like to define **the same folder, except just a different filename** (whether it is a new name like "randomNAME" or an iteration of the file "fileABC-backup01" shall be irrelevant). How can I reuse the input file so that I do not have to write it out again? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo cp /etc/var/more/evenMORE/file{ABC,DEF}` will copy `fileABC` as `fileDEF` in the same folder.
In general `cp /xyz/{file1,file2}` will copy `/xyz/file1` as `/xyz/file2`. Basically, put anything that is common outside the `{}` and separate the source and destination names with a , in the `{}`.

Comment: I edited the op to clarify the quesiton.

Comment: Where do you want the output file to be copied? In `/etc/var/more/evenMORE` or some other directory? Please put the full `cp` command that you would have used in the question.

Comment: Hey I wrote that! :) It should be in the same folder.

Comment: This will copy it in the same folder. Try it out.

Comment: But this is based on the false premise that the filenames begin in the same way. They sometimes do not. Just to appreciate it in full: yes, this is useful for these "iteration"-like operations. Thank you. :)

Comment: Edited to provide a generalized answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use this original file name over and over again, I suggest using it as such:

```
 OrigFile=/etc/var/more/evenMORE/fileABC
 sudo cp ${OrigFile} ${OrigFile}.bak
 sudo cp ${OrigFile} SomeRandomFile.txt
```

and every time you reference this `${OrigFile}` variable name, it will go fetch this file. Make it something short if you prefer to type less.

But if you are looking for a way the shell references it, like `$0` being the command and `$1` as the first argument, there is none.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to plan ahead a little you can put most of the path into a shell variable.

```
a="/etc/var/more/evenMORE"
sudo cp "$a/fileABC" "$a/randomNAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it in only one line this way:

```
sourcefile="/dir/filename"; sudo cp "$sourcefile" `dirname "$sourcefile"`/"new file name"
```